# How to Vectorize for loop/pandad iterrows with condition outside of loop python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, vectorization

I am trying to make a set of code I have faster using vectorization in Pandas (or NumPy).  I basically need to have a "trailing" condition as I loop through each row of a dataframe so that I can create a condition based on that.

example code:

```
lst1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6],
                     [7, 8, 9]])

lst2 = pd.DataFrame([[9, 8, 7],
                     [6, 5, 4],
                     [3, 2, 1]])

output_lst = pd.DataFrame(index=lst1.index, columns=lst1.columns)

previous_column_value_even = False
for row, values in lst1.iterrows():
        for col_index in values.index:
                value1 = lst1.loc[row, col_index]
                value2 = lst2.loc[row, col_index]
                if previous_column_value_even:
                    if value1 > value2:
                        output_lst.loc[row, col_index] = True
                        print(value1)

                if value1 % 2 == 0:
                        previous_column_value_even = True
                else:
                        previous_column_value_even = False
        previous_column_value_even = False
```

**output** 
9

[image]

- I'd like to have a vectorized form of this condition.
- The main thing I'm looking for is having an overall condition for each row that can be used in something like numpy.where(). I'd like to use numpy.where but pandas.dataframe.apply seems to be another option - I just can't figure out how to get the previous column's condition to be set as I "loop" through each column of a row in a vectorized form.
- This is my biggest constraint: having the condition dynamically go through the iteration of each column so that my second condition can be called. Preferably without a loop in the vectorized condition as that is my main problem

Comment: In an iterative program, when a variable involved in calculating step `i` is determined in step `i-1`, it [usually isn't vectorizable](https://cvw.cac.cornell.edu/vector/coding_dependencies). However your end goal seems to be speed rather than vectorization for its own sake, and there are other ways to do that: for example, using [numba JIT](https://numba.pydata.org/) wrappers over your numpy ops.

Answer (score 0):

Although I mentioned in my comment that programs like these aren't usually vectorizable, your code doesn't actually have the *read-after-write* dependency. In pure NumPy, we can simplify your code to something of the form:

```
import numpy as np

def process_arrays(A, B):
    C = np.zeros_like(A, dtype=np.bool)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(1, A.shape[1]): # no need to check column 0 for previous even
            if A[i, j - 1] % 2 == 0:
                if A[i, j] > B[i, j]:
                    C[i, j] = True
    return C
```

As the values of `previous_column_value_even` can all be computed independently in advance, so it should be possible to vectorize the above into:

```
C = np.where(np.logical_and(np.pad((A % 2) == 0, ((0, 0), (1, 0)))[:, :-1], A > B), True, False)
```